# Triangle angles

Tags: geometry, triangles

How would I prove that, in any triangle, any of the exterior angles is bigger than any of the remote interior angles?

[image]

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_angle_theorem

Comment: 20.2 in http://math.furman.edu/~dcs/courses/math36/lectures/l-20.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your figure above, let

$m \angle1 = a$
$m \angle2 = b$
$m \angle3 = c$
$m \angle4 = d$

We must show that $a > c$ and $a > d$.

Since all of the angles of a triangle must sum to $180^\circ$, we have

$b + c + d = 180$

Also, since $\angle1$ and $\angle2$ are supplementary:

$a + b = 180$

Reversing the second equality and adding to the first, we have

$(b + c + d) + 180 = 180 + (a + b)$
$\therefore a = c + d$

$a$, $c$ and $d$ are all positive, so if $a = c + d$, then $a$ *must* be greater than both $c$ and $d$.

Answer (score 0):

As $ \angle1 = \angle3 + \angle4 $

The above is because of the rule "exterior angle of a triangle is equal to sum of two the interior opposite angles" .

as this is true

1)   $ \angle1 = \angle3\ this\ is\ true\ iff \angle4=0 $   and

2)   $ \angle1 = \angle4\ this\ is\ true\ iff \angle3=0 $

But the above two violates the definition that triangle has 3 angles .
so none of them is zero and they are also positive(as angles are always positive measuring anticlockwise by convention). so the above two possibilities of being equal are ruled out .

if a quantity is equal to sum of two other positive quantities.....

sum will be greater than either of the two quantities added .

so
$ \angle1 > \angle3\ $

and

$ \angle1 > \angle4\ $

Answer (score 0):

I am going to do it in the simplest way so accept it

You know

1+2=180.........(A)

&     2+3+4=180........(B)

Putting (B) in(A) we get

1+2=2+3+4

So 1=3+4

Thus prooves 1 has be greater than 3 or 4

Comment: While this is correct, this is an answer on a very old question which does not contribute any new ideas or insights.